# EF 4.1 Code First and Membership

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I did go through the suggest similar questions and most were very outdated since all the new developments with EF Code First.    I'm looking for ideas or some way around this EF Code First "stumbling block".

Is there anyway to use the built in asp membership system with an EF Code First project?  One common Code First example is the Blog, Post, Comment like so (from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685467):

```
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string BloggerName { get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
  }

public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }
}
```

This is fabulous except that there is no way to track the user who posted a Comment.  Is there anything that can be done to make code first stuff like this work with asp.net membership?

The first thing that comes to mind is something like (just working with Comments here):

```
public class UserProfile
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string FavoriteColor { get; set; }
    //Other useless user profile stuff here
}    
public class Comment
{
    //Comment fields same as above
    public UserProfile Owner { get; set; }
}
```

The first thing that comes to mind is to change the Register action in the Account controller so when a user registers, their Guid (possibly their username as well) is also added to the UserProfile table created by EF Code First.  I guess this table would be a sort of bridge between my EF Code First tables and the asp.net membership tables.

Does this approach make any sense?  What are some pros/cons and are there any better options?

Answer (score 1):

Install the aspnet membership items into your database. You won't then be using CodeFirst on those entities. However, you can simply read who the user is from the MembershipProvider. Those tables can be queried directly if you need to (but the membership API should give you what you need)
You can also run the 'reverse engineer' tool from the entity framework power tools to give you the entities directly to work with.

You can get more info on installing into your DB here.
[Using HttpContext.Current.Application to store simple data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081972/using-httpcontext-current-application-to-store-simple-data)

The power tools are here to reverse engineer your tables into code first entities once they are added to the db:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's one way to do it.  Another is that you don't actually need to access the membership, all you need is the username, which when a user has been logged in via FormsAuthentication will populate the IPrincipal.

```
var username = User.Identity.Name;
```

or

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

Any other information you may need is accessible from the Membership API.

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
```

Don't be tempted to try and map the ASP.NET Membership tables into your data model, as this will cause problems with the default membership provider.  Just use the membership API to get any information you need.

Comment: I was tempted but I got over it =)  The best way currently available seems to be the second table which I usually use anyway to keep track of user information that aspnet membership doesn't track.  This might be another question but is there an attribute or some way to mark a property in my POCO as Required but not autogenerated?

Comment: I think you mean as a key, but not autogenerated.  Required does not imply any kind of autogeneration.  No, you wouldn't want to make it a key, At best you could make the field non-null in your database, and apply a unique constraint to it.  You probably would want an identity column as well (UserProfileID)

Comment: Considering usernames can change, I would consider linking it in by the provider id in place of or in addition to the user name (depends if your system allows deletion or deactivation of users)

Comment: @AdamTuliper - I've never seen a system where you can change your username after you've created it.  But still, for a simple blog that shouldn't matter.

Comment: @MystereMan I find that terribly hard to believe. You've never used windows, live id, almost any major site I take it - a SID is stored behind your account and the name can change at any time. In the default membership provider an id is stored behind the scenes as well and you can change the name. In addition so many systems are based upon an email login name, which can also change in literally almost any major site. Sites that support this are everywhere.

Comment: @AdamTuliper - I'm sorry, how do you change your live id?  As far as I can tell, you can't.  You can only create a new live id, since your live id is your email address, a new email adress means a new live id.

Comment: seriously? Login to windows live. on the _very first screen_ theres an option to change your login. In addition a simple google search reveals ways to do this.

Comment: @AdamTuliper - Did you try it?  If you do, you get "Your Windows Live ID can't be changed" "Your Windows Live ID can't be changed at this time."

Comment: no - have no need to try. The point is many sites provide this option (all windows systems as well). I did see some postings on that though where it was resolved for them by contacting support, so may want to go that route if you are looking for it. Hotmail and some other sourced emails don't work but some others do.