# HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Application sometimes empty

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET MVC+WebAPI application hosted in IIS.
I use `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Application` to store and share states across whole application, those states are key value pairs read from local file into memory in `Application_Start()`. However, when I retrieve those values from `ApiController`, sometimes the dictionary is empty and sometimes not, it seems the `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Application` what ApiController sees is a different instance from the one states were stored sometimes.
Does anyone know why? Is there a better and reliable way to share states across whole ASP.net application other than create static properties in Global.asax? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081972/using-httpcontext-current-application-to-store-simple-data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using HttpContext.Current.Application to store simple data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081972/using-httpcontext-current-application-to-store-simple-data)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using HttpContext.Current.Application to store simple data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081972/using-httpcontext-current-application-to-store-simple-data)

Comment: I don't think it is dup, what I want to figure out here is why sometimes the `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Application` is empty, as if it is a newly created instance.