# Is there any server side objects for saving the value for all users in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to save some value, by that, I need to check at all user's (maybe those all access from different machines) side that value will be is true or false, then need to proceed some further action.

I tried saving it to in '`session`' object but it's working only for one machine.

```
string InprocValue = Session["Inproc"]==null?"": Session["InprocLeadMobileNo"].ToString();
if (InprocValue == false)
{
    Session["Inproc"] = true;;
}
```

And also I like to avoid Database round trip frequently.
so, have any server-side objects where the application is hosted, then we can easily retrieve it from any user side and put it into `In-Process` on true/false condition base.

Comment: You can use `Application` instead of `Session`. It is common for all of the users.

Comment: I tried already like Application["Inproc"].ToString(); then getting an error : "The name 'Application' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: I'd say implement a proper caching mechanism outside of your application server memory

Comment: Are you running on multiple servers? If you are, you will need some central instance to store this value, be it a database or maybe a Redis Cache, or a file on a network share. If not, as Karan stated, you can use `httpContext.Application`.

Comment: What is your sever technology? Asp.net webform, asp.net mvc, asp.net mvc core?

Comment: Also, comparing a string `InprocValue` to `false` will result in a compile error.

Comment: Try with `HttpContext.Current.Application`.

Comment: The `httpContext::Application` was considered kind of "obsolete" from the very beginning because it doesn't introduce any value, rather - just an unnecessary layer of abstraction. There's really no point in using it in ASP.NET. Instead, one should have a static variable or use the memory cache provider. Example reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42523026/941240

Comment: @Wiktor Zychla.I already was implemented AppCode Class variables, but some of my friend not suggested for that..but it's working what I want..Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to change the Session mode from "InProc" to either StateServer or SqlServer.

For an overview of Session State modes, see this article:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx

For a session state server, check out Windows Server AppFabric, a high-performance in-memory cache that also can serve as a Session State Provider for ASP.NET:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849